# Hooking in to an archive page?

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks

I'm making a custom post type that I want to use in the form of a plugin - all pretty straight forward.

However, I want the archive page for this post type to look slightly different in the content area - how would I achieve this without having to ask the end user to move files to their template directory?

I hope that makes sense, if not please ask me to clarify further - I've not really been able to find anything in the codex, but maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `archive_template` filter in your plugin to override archive templates for a given post type, for example, `movies`:

```
<?php
function get_movies_archive_template( $archive_template ) {
     if ( is_post_type_archive ( 'movies' ) ) {
          $archive_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/movies-archive-template.php';
     }
     return $archive_template;
}
add_filter( 'archive_template', 'get_movies_archive_template' ) ;
```

See [archive_template in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/archive_template).

Comment: Looks like what I need - thanks! so I would make a custom file with a structure like get header - my custom content - get footer?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It have to be the regular WP template.